# Trying to avoid using Sheet.Activate when copying data

Tags: vba, excel

Running on Excel 2013 and I'm stumped. I'm trying to avoid having to activate the worksheet (let alone multiple lines of code) just to copy the data. Why would this work:

```
Sheets("DataDump").Activate
Range(Cells(startJobRow, 1), Cells(lastJobRow, 5)).Copy Sheets("DataRaw").Cells(lastDataRawRow + 1, 1)
```

But this does not:

```
Sheets("DataDump").Range(Cells(startJobRow, 1), Cells(lastJobRow, 5)).Copy Sheets("DataRaw").Cells(lastDataRawRow + 1, 1)
```

The second code gives me "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". If I manually select the worksheet "DataDump" while in debug mode and tell it to continue then it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example your use of Cells() is not qualified and this can cause problems.

In this case Cells() is referencing whichever sheet is active at the instant the line of code is evaluated.

You need to fully qualify Cells() in this case.

This should do it:

```
With Sheets("DataDump")
    .Range(.Cells(startJobRow, 1), .Cells(lastJobRow, 5)).Copy Sheets("DataRaw").Cells(lastDataRawRow + 1, 1)
End With
```

Comment: Nice thank you. I'm going to try a different route then. Kinda defeats the purpose of trying to keep it to a single line. Thank you for the clarification though!

Comment: Oooooor... Sheets("DataDump").Range(Sheets("DataDump").Cells(startJobRow, 1), Sheets("DataDump").Cells(lastJobRow, 5)).Copy Sheets("DataRaw").Cells(lastDataRawRow + 1, 1)
Thank you again for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: You are welcome. And yes there is no problem with doing it in one line. It's just long with repeated information, but as you found, it will work fine in one line. The fully qualified objects are the key.